# How to check fields exists in mongodb data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a doubt about how to check the field that exists in MongoDB data.

**classic DB**

```
{
 "product_name":"HHHHH"
 "product_category":"FFFFFFF",
"product_data":"HHHHHHHH"
}

{
 "product_name":"GGGGGG"
 "product_category":"TTTTTTTT",
"product_data":"VVVVVVVVV"
}
```

How to check two fields exists in classic DB.
Example:
This is my query

```
db.classic.findOne({$in:[{"product_name":"HHHHH", "product_category":"TTTTTTTT",}]})
```

This query is correct or incorrect

Comment: Do you want to find the document which either should have ```product_name``` as 'HHHHH' or ```product_category``` as 'TTTTTTTT'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check only if the field exists:

```
db.classic.find({ "product_name": { $exists: true }} )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use $in you have to use like this,

```
db.classic.findOne( { 'product_name': { $in: ['HHHHH'] }, 'product_category': { $in: ['TTTTTTTT'] } } )
```

You can just use $exists to check whether a field exists in a record or not. It does not compare the value. It will return the record with field containing any value.

```
db.classic.findOne( { 'product_name': { $exists: true }, 'product_category': { $exists: true } } )
```